# Does AWS DocumentDB support pymongo .hint at all?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pymongo-3.x, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a large but simple collection in DocumentDB (3.6) and need to quickly and efficiently retrieve all document ids matching a simple regex pattern.

On the cli I can search for these with a regex and hint and seem to get good results via explain.

When I try to transfer this to a call from pymongo I get an error saying the index cannot be found... which is odd as its _id I'm hinting for and I can clearly see it defined on the cli.

Am I going crazy or is there no way to hint in pymongo when using DocumentDB?

How could I work around this issue if not possible? Does it make sense to go as far as calling the mongo cli from a system call within python (seems excessive...)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to use hint with pymongo. You can append hint to your find command -

```
collection.find({'name': 'foo'}).hint(index_name')
```